Уточнение по процессу согласования в React: сравнение React элементов и Fiber узлов в work-in-progress и current деревьях
Я пытаюсь разобраться, как именно работает процесс согласования (reconciliation) в React, особенно в части, где происходят обновления и сравнения React элементов с Fiber узлами.
Вот что я понимаю на данный момент:

При первичной инициализации React создает дерево React элементов из
JSX, а затем строит дерево Fiber узлов, соответствующее каждому
элементу.
При вызове setState нужный Fiber узел помечается для обновления, и
начинается создание work-in-progress дерева. Fiber узлы, которые не
изменились, клонируются из текущего дерева, а в компоненте, где
вызван setState, генерируется новое дерево React элементов.

Вопросы:

Во время процесса сверки (reconciliation) новый React элемент будет
сравниваться с Fiber узлом из current дерева, или сначала он
обернется в новый Fiber узел, и затем будет происходить сравнение
между Fiber узлами из work-in-progress и current деревьев?
Также хотелось бы понять, запускается ли процесс сверки только после
того, как work-in-progress дерево будет полностью построено, или
сверка происходит постепенно по мере создания каждого узла в
work-in-progress дереве?


https://7km.top/algorithm/diff#%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC%E5%8E%9F%E7%90%86 ответ на первый вопрос
